# How to fit a curve to a dozen local and global minima and boundary data points?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, curve-fitting, splines

I have a very sparse time series dataset that primarily consists of 3-12 local and global minimums and maximums as well as both boundary points. Is there a way I can fit a curve (preferably non-parametric) through these few points?

Is there a way to have interpolation via cubic splines, gaussian processeses or some other method respect my datapoints as max/min values rather than just undifferentiated datapoints. Fitting curves using these methods tend to overshoot, sometimes by a lot, my local/global min/max points.

If these methods can't be modified, is there another method that can fit a curve to a dozen or so boundary points and local/global min/max values?